# how to make a list with functions

Tags: python

i have a function that makes random values in a list. now i want to make a list that indexes are these random lists.
the random maker function :

```
def ran():
     h1=random.randint(40,240)
     h2=random.randint(40,240)
     h3=random.randint(80,240)
     t1=random.randint(5,20)
     t2=random.randint(5,20)
     t3=random.randint(4,12)
     xx=[h1,t1,h2,t2,h3,t3]
     return xx
```

next function :

```
def particle(xj):
    for j in range(20):
        xj[j]=ran()
        return xj
```

this function only gave me the first index, i want 20. how can i fix it?
this is what i get for example :

```
[[176, 8, 83, 5, 110, 12]]
```

(first function works perfectly)

Comment: Maybe reduce the indentation level of the `return` statement by one? It's returning at the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

the position of `return` is wrong.

you should put it like:

```
def particle():
    xj = [0 for x in range(20)]
    for j in range(20):
        xj[j]=ran()
    return xj
```

Comment: it says  list assignment index out of range

Comment: it works if i do this :    def particle(xj):
    for j in range(3):
        xj[j]=ran()
    return xj

e=particle([0,0,0])
print(e)

Comment: @ParKho if it says "index out of range", then you can allocate a list for xj first. I have modified the code.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, quicker and more performant, using list comprehension:

```
def particle():
    return [ran() for _ in range(20)]
```

Usage:

```
xj = particle()
```

Comment: No? Show your code and the errors you get. I will help

Comment: i tried something like this before and it didn't work. now it did. thank you

Comment: Ah, very nice, I am glad